# 2 ISP’s, 2 Routers I need redundancy and load balancing

Tags: router, switch, load-balancer

I am thinking of upgrading my network I am gonna get two CCR2216 routers and do VRRP the thing is if I had a single router I would plug both the isp to same router and load balance since I have two routers now how do I connect the isp cable.

Comment: In my own experience, one does load balancing with a load balancing router.

Comment: Load balancing requires a device inside your network and a device outside your network. These two devices will handling the splitting and reassembling of your network traffic and testing of the connections in order to tell which connection they should route traffic over between them. With your setup you could probably do some sort of resiliency setup, where you have a primary internet source and your router can quickly switch to another if that primary goes down, but that is not "load balancing".

Comment: No i mean CCR2216 can do load balancing but there are two of them so how do i connect them together